# 'UndefVarError: `Dataframe` not defined' from Python to Julia

Tags: julia

I'm getting 'UndefVarError: `Dataframe` not defined' when trying to create a new dictionary key with any empty dataframe call.   I have all the necessary includes above this code and it does the python/julia conversion correctly if I comment out the "Dataframe()" lines.

```
import numpy as np
import julia
import pandas as pd
import random
import copy

jl = julia.Julia(runtime=jpath, compiled_modules=False) 

from julia import Base
from julia import Main
from julia import DataFrames
from julia import Pandas
from julia import Tables
from julia import Distributed

datadict={}
n = 10
randomlist = []
for i in range(0,n):
    num = random.randint(1,100)
    randomlist.append(num)

data = {
    'Score': list(randomlist),
        'ScoreBin': list(np.zeros(n))
           }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Score', 'ScoreBin'])


datadict["first_df"]=df
datadict["second_df"]=df

Main.datadict = datadict;
Main.eval("""

dictj = Dict(datadict)

for (key, value) in datadict
    dictj[key] = datadict[key] |> Pandas.DataFrame|> DataFrames.DataFrame;
end

             
dictj["first_df_mod"] = Dataframe()
for i = 1:length(dictj["first_df"][:, :Score])
    if dictj["first_df"][i, :Score] > 50
        dictj["first_df_mod"][i, :ScoreBin] = 1 
    end
end

dictj["second_df_mod"] = Dataframe()
for i = 1:length(dictj["second_df"][:, :Score])
    if dictj["second_df"][i, :Score] > 50
        dictj["second_df_mod"][i, :ScoreBin] = 1 
    end
end

dfjp=Dict(dictj)
for (key, value) in dictj
    dfjp[key] = dictj[key] |> Pandas.DataFrame;
end

"""
)
```

Tried different constructs to create a datframe but they did not work.

Comment: It's likely because the name of the struct (and constructor) is `DataFrame`, not `Dataframe`. Fixing that spelling error should resolve that problem.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, I had to add the package name - DataFrames.DataFrame() 
 and it finally worked!!